# Split a string into characters excluding the whitespace

Tags: python

I have a code :

```
import re
def sam(str)
 data=re.split(r'(\w)',str)
 print data

if __name__== "__main__":
 sam('hello how are you')
```

I get an output of:

```
["","h","e","l","l","o","","h","o","w",""....]
```

I want to split each character of these words excluding the white space. How can I get an output of:

```
["h","e","l","l","o","h","o","w",....]
```

The difference being there are no whitespace/blank entries.

Comment: Use `==` for equality instead of `=`, and don't forget `:` after `if` conditions. Next time try to not type the code here, just copy/paste it.

Comment: Also, `sam` should really be taking an argument. It looks like you retyped this code into the question box instead of copy/pasting from known working code. In the future, copy/paste. It's far more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

```
[char for char in string if not char.isspace()]
```

or if you only care about the ASCII space character, rather than all whitespace,

```
list(string.replace(' ', ''))
```

or if you really wanted to keep only characters that match `\w`:

```
re.findall(r'\w', string)
```

The `findall` version will only keep letters, numbers, and underscores. If that's what you want, go ahead and use it.

Comment: How can I use it by passing a string to my function sam()?

Comment: @NBA: Define `sam` to take an argument named `string`. If you don't know how to do that, the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) should answer your questions.

Comment: Can I use --> re.split(r'(\w)',str) to achieve this?

Comment: @NBA: No. I don't think it works the way you think it does. You could use `re.findall` if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

use `str.replace`:

```
In [805]: list(s.replace(' ', ''))
Out[805]: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'o', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u']
```

or `str.translate`:

```
In [808]: list(s.translate(None, ' '))
Out[808]: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'o', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u']
```

They are times faster than list comprehension (as @user2357112 mentioned) in dealing with long strings:

```
In [827]: s2='hello how are you'*10000

In [828]: timeit [char for char in s2 if not char.isspace()]
100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop

In [889]: timeit [char for char in s2 if char != ' ']
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

In [829]: timeit list(s2.replace(' ', ''))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.4 ms per loop

In [830]: timeit list(s2.translate(None, ' '))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.87 ms per loop
```

Comment: [char for char in s2 if not ' '] is approximately double.

Comment: @JustinPoehnelt add that case, should be `if char != ' '`, because `not ' '` always returns `False` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just use list and [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), no need for any regexp here.

```
>>> list('hello how are you'.replace(' ', ''))
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'o', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u']
```